# User prompt for downstream job

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jobs

I would have **job1** with one dropdown parameter - ENV (DEV, QA, etc) which run and download some files from git repo, and after this it should run **job2** which has several another parameters that would be filled via Extended Choise Plugin from downloaded files during **job1**.

And this **job2** should wait for user to check/edit default values of these parameters.

And after setting all parameters user can press Build button to start building.
I don't need to auto-run job2 because I need user to see all the parameters from job1.

Is it possible in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipeline and in the steps you can ask user for user input to accept or decline for the second job. This way, you can also be notified via an email when the first job completes. 
Just refer to the `input` in the pipeline syntax options.

Comment: thank you, I've read about input, but seems it is not that I need - it is only shows two links Proceed or Abort. But I need to show somehow the page of job2 with all the parameters. Like you click on link Build with Parameters